# What is the difference between options and custom fields (meta) in Wordpress?

Tags: posts

What is the difference between options and custom fields (meta) in Wordpress?

I want to add more fields to website but need to know when best to use the above . What case calls for use of options (is it that this is for site wide setting) ? What is the case for custom fields (meta) for working with posts/pages only?

Comment: options are general values, site wide (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/). and meta are associated to a page, post or custom post, there are like fields of the custom post which is a object (https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Answer (score 0):

Options are the value which can be used for mostiny  storing settings value. We also can say, It is the value similar to config variable. Which can be use any where in the site and will be same for all the objects.

Whereas Custom fields are only for posts, and its values are store as meta. So Its value will be different for all the post. Or we can say its kind property of each post.

In Short, Global values are store as Options 
and values related to Posts are store as Meta.

Hope this will help you.